# How to get client(user) browser timezone in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, timezone

How to find client(user) browser timezone in magento 2?

Comment: You can use GeoIP or Javascript.

Comment: catch `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` and translate it with GeoIP plugin or remote service

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in plain Javascript:

```
var myDate = new Date();
document.write(myDate.getTimezoneOffset());
```

More info here: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/